# Changing the file name from servlet-name-servlet.xml file name to spring.xml using context-param and listener tag.

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am new to Spring-MVC and learning it.
I am trying a simple hello-world programme using Spring-MVC and my goal(task) was to change servlet-name-servlet.xml file name to spring.xml(user-defined name)
I have tried using init-param tag by specifying the path in param-value tag its working fine!!!
**But, My concern is changing the file name from servlet-name-servlet.xml file name to spring.xml using context-param and listener tag.**

---

I am getting R.E -
IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hello-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hello-servlet.xml]

---

index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<form action="./hello.htm">
<pre>
Enter Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</pre>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

success.jsp

```
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
${msg}
```

---

HelloController.java

```
public class HelloController  extends AbstractController{

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        Map m = new HashMap();
        m.put("msg","Hello..."+ name);
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("success",m);
        return mav;
    }

}
```

---

spring.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Handler -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="mappings">
<props>
<prop key="/hello.htm">h</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>

<!-- Controller -->
<bean id="h" class="com.controller.HelloController">
</bean>

<!-- ViewResolver -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/output/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

---

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
         <!-- using init-param the code is working fine -->
          <!--<init-param> 
              <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
              <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value> 
            </init-param> -->
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

I have added all the required jars using maven dependencies.
Can I change the pre-defined file name(servlet-name-servlet.xml) to  user-defined file name (spring.xml) using context-param and listener tag? What is wrong in my code?

Comment: What is `hello-servlet.xml`?

Comment: Spring has recommended to use (servlet-name - servlet.xml) i.e- hello-servlet.xml 
but, wanted to change the file name to spring.xml (user-defined name).
hello is just user-defined name to map servlet tag to servlet-mapping tag using a servlet-name tag as done in web.xml file.

Comment: You need to provide the dispatcher xml file (`hello-servlet.xml` in your case). This is where the Spring MVC is configured. While the `spring.xml` is where you configure other components to be used in spring container.

Comment: @W-S Yes, I know that but, I need to change the pre-defined dispatcher xml file name (hello-servlet.xml) to spring.xml name. Can I do that using context-param and listener tag?
I tried this case bcoz change of file name to spring.xml is working fine using  init-param tag

Comment: `ContextLoaderListener` (or `ContextLoaderServlet`) and `DispatcherServlet` [load two different Spring `ApplicationContext`s](http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Spring-ContextLoaderListener-And-DispatcherServlet-Concepts). The former reads the configuration files specified under the `context-param` tag, while the later reads the file specified by the `init-param` tag under the servlet definition. Therefore, pointing the dispatcher servlet to a different file name or location through the `context-param` tag is not possible.

Comment: @manish Thank you for your suggestion.